# Using ffmpeg to encode from yuv to m4v with MPEG-4 encoder

Tags: 14.04, compiling, ffmpeg, codecs

I am trying to encode a raw yuv file to m4v as follows:

`ffmpeg -s cif -r 30 -b 64000 -bt 3200 -g 30 -i akiyo_cif.yuv -vcodec mpeg4 a02.m4v`

But it did not work and I got this error from the console output:

> ffmpeg version 2.4.3-1ubuntu1~trusty6 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
>     built on Nov 22 2014 17:07:19 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
>     configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1ubuntu1~trusty6' --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --extra-cflags= --extra-cxxflags= --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --shlibdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libxvid --enable-libx265 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzvbi --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libsoxr --enable-openal --enable-libopencv
>
> libavutil      54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
>   libavcodec     56.  1.100 / 56.  1.100
>   libavformat    56.  4.101 / 56.  4.101
>   libavdevice    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
>   libavfilter     5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
>   libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
>   libswscale      3.  0.100 /  3.  0.100
>   libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
>   libpostproc    53.  0.100 / 53.  0.100
>
> Option b (video bitrate (please use -b:v)) cannot be applied to input file akiyo_cif.yuv -- you are trying to apply an input option to an output file or vice versa. Move this option before the file it belongs to.
>
> Error parsing options for input file akiyo_cif.yuv
>
> Error opening input files: Invalid argument

The `akiyo_cif.yuv` file can be foud here:

http://trace.eas.asu.edu/yuv/akiyo/akiyo_cif.7z

Can anyone help me with this please, I really need to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have placed your *bitrate* option in the incorrect place as the error is telling you:

```
Option b (video bitrate (please use -b:v)) cannot be applied to input file 
akiyo_cif.yuv -- you are trying to apply an input option to an output file 
or vice versa. Move this option before the file it belongs to.
```

Remembering that the FFmpeg options always use this flow:

```
ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...
```

The following adjusted syntax applies the corrected bitrate option to the *output file* rather than the *input file*:

```
ffmpeg -s cif -r 30 -i akiyo_cif.yuv -c:v mpeg4 -b:v 64k -bt 32k -g 30 a02.m4v
```

The quality of the output file is not all that great as you have specified a quite low bitrate, but this can of course be adjusted. Something like the following better quality video encode settings looks great on my system:

```
ffmpeg -s cif -r 30 -i akiyo_cif.yuv -c:v mpeg4 -q:v 5 a02.m4v
```

But perhaps you have a very specific need for your output video that this will not suit...

Comment: Thank you @andrew.46 your reply has really helped me. Now i can go forward with my project on evalvid.